# Google Maps: Not all markers are showing at certain zoom levels

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to show all of my markers at all zoom levels of Google Maps.  The locations are retrieved via AJAX from a JSON file generated by a database.  Here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/faculty/create-members-json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].user_latitude, data[i].user_longitude),
                 map: map
            });

        marker.set('info', data[i]);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(data) {
               info = this.get('info');
               infowindow.setContent(setInfo(info));
               infowindow.open(map, this);
            })
        }
     }
 });
```

How do I make sure I am showing all the markers at any zoom level?  Everything else works fine.

**SOLVED:**  I needed `map.getBounds()` in the AJAX call.  Now it works.

Comment: Also, I want only those in a certain radius.  The map will pull in all locations globally (which I want), but I only want to display those in a certain radius.

Comment: Either close your question, or add your own solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I needed `map.getBounds()` in the AJAX call. Now it works.